# How can I create an SBT task to test the scala code in Play Framework

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.6

I am using `IntelliJ` for development. I have created a `test` folder which has my `spec` files. To test the `spec`s, I right click on the project directory and chose `run->all tests`.

I want to create an `sbt` task to test the code. I know that I'll have to define the tast in `build.sbt` but I don't know the command which will run the tests.

Which is the command to run tests in play? The documentation says (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Testing-your-application-with-ScalaTest)

`You can run tests from the Play console. To run all tests, run test.`. But I don't know how to get to play console.

Answer (score 0):

I will be happy to accept better answer. I have done following so far which seem to work. Basically, to run `play` tests, I need to call `sbt test`. `play console` is just a wrapper over `sbt console`. In my `build.sbt`, I wrote the following tasks. These tasks are similar to going to top level project directory in `cmd` or a `terminal` and running `sbt test`.

In build.sbt

```
def runBackendTests(implicit dir:File):Int = runScript("sbt test")

lazy val `backend-test` = taskKey[Unit]("Run Backend tests when testing application.")

`backend-test` := {
  implicit val backendRoot = baseDirectory.value //this should be top level project directory. The tests are in test directory in this directory
  println("backend root is ",backendRoot)
  if(runBackendTests != 0) throw new Exception("Backend tests failed")
}
```